# UIScrollView images not loading

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am using FSPagerView to create an elegant UIScrolView with multiple images. I am trying to follow the [documentation](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSPagerView#page_control) however I am getting an error while trying to load the images from my imagesArray. [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K56GA.png)

```
var imageArray = [UIImage(named: "LA"),UIImage(named: "SF"), UIImage(named: "NY"), UIImage(named: "Miami"), UIImage(named: "LasVegas"), UIImage(named: "Chicago")]

@IBOutlet weak var pagerView: FSPagerView!{

    didSet{
        self.pagerView.register(FSPagerViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

}

public func numberOfItems(in pagerView: FSPagerView) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count
}

public func pagerView(_ pagerView: FSPagerView, cellForItemAt index: Int) -> FSPagerViewCell {
    let cell = pagerView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", at: index)
  cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: self.imageArray[index])
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imageArray` is an array of `UIImage`-s not `String` -s, You should assign the image directly

```
cell.imageView?.image =  self.imageArray[index]
```

this `UIImage(named` is used to load an image with that name from main Bundle

```
let image = UIImage(named:"imageName.png")
```